# Numbering in sequence

Tags: numbering

We have surveyed about 3000 acres land and and divided it into about 4000 land parcel's and we were asked to number them in sequence starting from Northwest to southeast
Is there any plugin or code to make the process easier.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What software are you using, and what type of data do you have? Are they polygons?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works